# Django template not rendering on webpage

Tags: django, django-templates

Directory structure -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNtk6.png

settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '...xxx...'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'personal'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'personal/mainx.html')
```

mainx.html (mysite\personal\templates\personal\mainx.html)

```
...
    <body>
    <h1>Hello There</h1>
    <div>
        {% block content %}

        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    </body>
...
```

home2.html (mysite\personal\templates\personal\home2.html)

```
{% extends "personal/mainx.html" %}

{% block content %}

<p>Hey! Welcome to my website! Well, I wasn't expecting guests. Um, my name is Harrison. I am a programmer.</p>

{% endblock %}
```

*Setup : Installed Django using pip install > created project > created app > configured n wrote html files*

**Output** https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLQ2s.png

Why it is not rendering the template paragraph text?

Comment: What is the issue? Hows your view look like?

Comment: It is showing only the contents in mainx.html (h1 tag), its not taking the template text written in home2.html.

Comment: your `home2.html` is the same directory level as `mainx.html` so you only need `{% extends "mainx.html" %}`

Comment: I tried it already, it didn't work.

Comment: show your settings.py file code

Comment: Please put your views.py file. Need to see the method by which you are rendering it.

Comment: Added settings.py & views,py. Everything is as generated by default - just added my app in settings.py.

Comment: change in views.py to `return render(request, 'personal/home2.html')` beecause home2.html extends mainx.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In templates we have to render the file having filling content for template & use the file having template content as 'extends' parameter in file having filling content for template.

For example, in above situation "mainx.html" is the template file and "home2.html" is the file having content that is to be rendered on webpage in the structure provided by "mainx.html".
That's why when we render file in "views.py", we will render the "home2.html".

The correct definition of function "index" in "views.py" will be this :

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'personal/home2.html')
```